# Nonsensical month days displayed in Bootstrap UI DateTimePicker popup calendar

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm experiencing a problem using Bootstrap UI + Bootstrap UI DateTimePicker (https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker) where nonsensical days are included as the left-most column on the calendar popup. See the screenshot below. From top to bottom, the days that should not be there are 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36. They are present no matter what month I switch to.

[image: Left-most column of non-existent days]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe those are weeks. (31 is the 31st week of the year)

You should be able to change this behavior by setting `show-weeks` to `false` in the `datepickerOptions`.

See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker for details.